# get parents (and their parents,...) from table with self relationship in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been breaking my head over this, but without any succes... I have following self-reverencing table (`Table A`):

```
ID |EmployeeID | ParentID | Level |
1  |11         | null     | A     |
2  |12         | 11       | B     |
3  |13         | 12       | C     |
4  |14         | 12       | C     |
```

(it's not well build, but we can't change that anymore)

I need to create a view that gives following result:

```
ID | EmployeeID | Level | LevelA   | LevelB   | LevelC   | LevelD 
1  | 11         | A     | 11       | null     | null     | null   
2  | 12         | B     | 11       | 12       | null     | null   
3  | 13         | C     | 11       | 12       | 13       | null   
4  | 14         | C     | 11       | 12       | 14       | null
```

`ID`, `EmployeeID` and `Level` come directly from `Table A`.

`Level A - D` gives the parent of that `EmployeeID` and the next parents in hierarchy. If the Level of the Employee is C, you can say it is a C-level employee so his ID is in column LevelC. His Parent is a B-Level employee, so his ID comes in column LevelB. His patent is a A-level employee (which is the highest rank) and his ID comes in column LevelA.

The empty levels just stay `null`.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.EMPLOYEEID, A.LEVEL, PT.A, PT.B, PT.C, PT.D
FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT ID, EMPLOYEEID, LEVEL FROM TABLEA) AS SOURCETABLE
PIVOT (
MAX([EMPLOYEEID])
FOR LEVEL IN ([A], [B], [C], [D])) AS PIVOTTABLE
) AS PT
ON A.ID = PT.ID
```

This code Works as long as you have four columns, but you'll see null values in the columns not matched by the pivot.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use Common Table Expression (CTE)

```
With MyCTE
As (SELECT EmployeeID, ParentID, Level
    FROM tableA
    WHERE ParentID IS NULL
 UNION ALL
    SELECT EmployeeID, ParentID, Level
    FROM tableA a join MyCTE c
       ON c.EmployeeID = a.ParentID
    WHERE a.ParentID IS NOT NULL )
 SELECT * FROM MyCTE
```

You really don't even need the Level column in the table

```
With MyCTE
As (SELECT EmployeeID, ParentID, 1 Level
    FROM tableA
    WHERE ParentID IS NULL
 UNION ALL
    SELECT a.EmployeeID, a.ParentID, Level + 1 Level
    FROM tableA a join MyCTE c
       ON c.EmployeeID = a.ParentID
    WHERE a.ParentID IS NOT NULL )
 SELECT * FROM MyCTE
```

to just add the extra columns, you can use [Pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx),

Comment: ... and then pivot that result to get the desired result.

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing this wrong, but I get the exact same result when I do `SELECT EmployeeID, ParentID, Level FROM tableA` which is just the same as my Original table except for the ID and not like the view I hoped to get...?

Comment: Then your problem is not the heiarchical data, it is simply adding the pivot columns,  Use PIVOT function 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx